# how should i go about a TypeError function() takes exactly 2 arguments(1 given)

Tags: django, django-views

i have two views,

```
def create_order(request,id):
    orders = Order()
    orders.restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
    orders.save()

    if orders.pk:
        ....
    return orders
```

the second view calls the first one,

```
def show_checkout(request,id):
    if order.is_empty(request):
        ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,instance=restaurant)
        if form.is_valid():
            order_created = create_order(request,restaurant)
            .......
    return render_to_response('checkout/checkout.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

i when i run this i get error `

show_checkout() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`
My Traceback,

```
Traceback:
File "/home/matsinvasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /orders/checkout/
Exception Value: show_checkout() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

i go about this and suggesting a good read on dealing with arguments is appreciated

```
from .views import show_item, show_order,get_category,homepage,show_checkout,reciept
from f4l import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',homepage,name="homepage"),
    url(r'^menu/(\d+)$',get_category, name="f4l_menu"),
    url(r'^your_order/$',show_order,name="order_index"),
    url(r'^item/(?P<id>\w+)/$',show_item, name="item_order"),
    url(r'^checkout/$',show_checkout,name="checkout"),
    url(r'^reciept/$',reciept,name="checkout_reciept"),
)
```

fixing urls.py, raises `NoReverseMatch error` in this function,

```
Reverse for 'checkout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
    def get_checkout_url(request):
        return urlresolvers.reverse('checkout')
```

Comment: can you post your `urls.py`?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony i just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `show_checkout` view is taking a second `id` parameter that you are not accounting for in your URLs.

You need to add it to your URL as follows:

```
url(r'^checkout/(?P<checkout_id>[\w|\W]+)$',show_checkout,name="checkout"),
```

And when you call the URL in your template, you need to pass the `id` that you are asking for in the view like so:

```
{% url checkout checkout.id %}
```

Or if you are using Django 1.5:

```
{% url 'checkout' checkout.id %}
```

Comment: am trying out your answer, and i get error in another function, checkout my edit.

Comment: Again you are calling the `show_checkout` view without it's required `id` parameter. You need to change the return statement to `return urlresolvers.reverse('checkout', args=(whatever_your_checkout_id_variable_is,))`

Comment: You should also take a good look at the documentation for `reverse` and `{% url %}` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls